# Font and textColor are gone - Yet another UITableViewCell awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib, awakefromnib

I don't know if this is specific to `UITableViewCells` but rather general for `UIViews`  (as i believe) but i noticed the *problem* with a  cell.

As mentioned, I have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass which loads itself from a xib when it gets initialized with an designated init:

```
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    self = nib[0];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It has a `UILabel` as an outlet and I set some properties of it in the `awakeFromNib` method:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.labelLeft.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.labelLeft.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
}
```

The point is, that the label **doesn't keep** the textColor nor the font and I don't understand why.
`awakeFromNib` gets called and the outlet is connected right, since i can set the text.

I can make it work by settings those properties after I set his text in the `UITableViewDataSource` but I don't feel it's the right way and I want to understand why this doesn't work.

**Question**:
Why doesn't it keep the Font and Textcolor and what can I do to make it work the right way?

Comment: "which loads itself from a xib" - here's the problem. I bet if you created the cell programmatically, it would work.

Comment: Yeah, if i would have it done all by code it definitely would have worked. But i want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Well it kinda works. It just doesn't keep the color and Font...

Comment: "If there is no answer after 30 min. on StackOverflow, there is no solution to your problem." - quote anonymous da internez.

Comment: I have the same issue. Yes, I can setting new font and color in every update method of the cell, but I wont to set it only once.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet either.

Comment: I found where the problem was. Try to explain more detail in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue with all my labels loaded from `.Nib`'s. Then I found that the problem was in `UIAppearance`. I have the following line in my `AppDelegate`:

```
+ (void)styleApplication {
    [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[MGStylesheet defaultLightFontOfSize:17]];
}
```

This method update all fonts in my application, and all works fine, until I start loading my `UIView`'s from `.Nib`. When I removed this, everything start working as expected.

Comment: Yeah of course UIAppearance! Just put the code in `-layoutSubviews` after you call super and it works. Makes totaly sense!

Answer (score -1):

Set the attributes of  the label in the nib-file. If you split your interface configuration to different places this causes just trubble.

If you don't want to do that move the configuration of the label into `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: My question was why it doesn't work, **not** what can I do else.